# python binary tree recursion

Tags: python, recursion, binary-tree

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,value):
        self.value = value 
        self.right = None
        self.left = None

class Tree:
    def __init__(self,root):
        self.root = Node(root) 

    def print_tree(self):
        return self.preorder_print(self.root,"")

    def preorder_print(self,start,traversal):
        if start:
            print('step 1')
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)
            print('step 2')
            traversal +=(str(start.value)+"-")
            print('step 3')
            traversal = self.preorder_print(start.right, traversal)
        return traversal


"""
             F
        B         G
    A      D        I
        C    E   H 

In- order print: A->B->C->D->E->F->G->H->I
"""


tree = Tree("F")
tree.root.left = Node("B")
tree.root.right = Node("G")
tree.root.right.right = Node("I")
tree.root.right.right.left = Node("H")

tree.root.left.left = Node("A")
tree.root.left.right = Node("D")
tree.root.left.right.left = Node("C")
tree.root.left.right.right = Node("E")
print(tree.print_tree())
```

I understand the 'step 1' recursion goes to the deep left, Node("A"), but when after reaching A,

1. how does the func break out of that recursion? Does it move on to the next line, "step 2"?
2. what's the return value of that traversal in 'step 1'?

Comment: In #2 what is "A"?

Comment: @ScottHunter `"A"` is obviously `Node("A")`

Comment: Does this actually work when you run it? You don't seem to ever return a value anywhere and you never do any sort of check to see if there is still a node to the left or right.

Comment: @SeanPayne: Its all there: `return traversal` and `if start:`.

Comment: @quamrana Thank you. It's late at night here. I spent a few hours debugging. Clearly it's time to stop working xD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, there are lots of programmers who have trouble visualising recursion.
2. Yes, when the recursion reaches `Node A` the recursion does help.
3. The function breaks out of the recursion (the base case) at the `if start:` statement.

by the way, your code, as posted, outputs this: `A-B-C-D-E-F-G-H-I-`

An example of the base case for your data is this: When the code enters `preorder_print()` with `start` referring to `Node("A")`, then `if start:` passes and the next statement is `traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)` which passes `start.left` to the next level down.

Now because `Node("A")` has both `left` and `right` set to the default `None`, the above call is a `nop` and just returns `traversal`, so the next statement is the `traversal += str(start.value) + "-"` where `start.value` is `"A"`.

Again the next statement `traversal = self.preorder_print(start.right, traversal)` is a `nop` and then `return traversal` exits this level and goes up one level.

Now we find ourselves back in `self.preorder_print()` having just executed `traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)` where `start` refers to `Node("B")` and `start.left` refers to `Node("A")`.

Comment: for your third response, when the func breaks out of the recursion, does it move on to the next line, traversal +=(str(start.value)+"-")?

Comment: The `break out of the recursion` is the `if start:` which skips the `traversal = ...` parts and jumps to `return traversal` and returns up one level, to, yes, presumably the `traversal += ... `

Comment: Plz correct me if I'm wrong. `traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)` is the recursion line that goes all the way down to `Node(A)`. At next cycle, the recursion will break at `if start:`, and returns the value `A` to its parent node, `Node(B)`, one level above `Node(A)` and assign that value `A` to the variable `traversal` in the line `traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)` ?

Comment: 1. for the `Node(A)` is `nop`, does that mean the left var `traversal` in `traversal = self.preorder_print(start.left, traversal)` marks the position of the current Node so the next line `traversal +=(str(start.value)+"-")` can concatenate `start.value` as A to the string?   2. I am still bit shaky on the last line of func `return traversal`. Does it just go one level above?

Comment: Do you want a [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214838/recursion)?